# What is the best way to read and unzip files in mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, zip

I want to read and unzip files in mobile browsers on iPhone and Android, what is the best possible solution. Is there a java script way, I don't want a round trip to server.
I need the minimal dependency, so flash is ruled out, any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has no file access so it cannot access the zip files stored on disk ..

--

Take a look at

1. [JSXCompressor](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/2009/09/29/jsxcompressor-zlib-compressed-javascript-code/), which zip/unzip implementation in javascript  (although you need to somehow feed it the data ..)

Comment: that's the question, how to do that using standard methods, I guess Flash can do it, but I am looking for best alternative.

Comment: i am not a mobile developer so i do not know if ActiveX exists there (most likely not). If it does it can handle it .. (update answer to provide some links..)

Comment: ActiveX (being a Windows technology) certainly doesn't exist on the iPhone (Apple / BSD) or Android (Google / Linux). And Flash can't do it on the iPhone, since it isn't supported by the platform.

Comment: @David Dorward, have a look at the jsxcompressor link... might be what you are after..

Comment: @Gaby — I’m not after anything…

Comment: @David, lol did not mean that in some bad way ... 'what you are after' as in usefull at what you are trying to do

Comment: @Gaby — I'll rephrase: I am not Priyank Bolia. I did not ask the question.

Comment: @David , oups ... sorry for the mix-up and thanks for the heads up .. needed that :)

Comment: I don't think it can have zip files, it just some basic compression of data, zip files contain multiples files inside them, have some header and blah blah... This won't work, and modifying it to support zip files will take years for a novice like me.

Comment: There's a Javscript unzip library.  see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163857/unzipping-zip-archives-with-javascript-in-firefox-3-6

Answer (score 0):

There's a Javascript library that unzips basic ZIP files. 
[Unzipping zip archives with JavaScript in Firefox 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163857/unzipping-zip-archives-with-javascript-in-firefox-3-6)

Comment: at least the js-zip demo didn't worked for me in Firefox 3.6.

Comment: if you have a particular problem I might be able to help you through it.