# Unzipping zip archives with JavaScript in Firefox 3.6

Tags: javascript, firefox, compression, html, zip

I am toying with an application that will demo some Firefox 3.6 specific functionality, most of which are listed here: http://demos.hacks.mozilla.org/openweb/

I want to drag a zip file in the browser, unzip it, and work with the unzipped contents.

Are there any existing libraries that can do this? Does FireFox 3.6 in particular have something I can use? Or would I have to roll my own unzipper library?

---

For the record: http://github.com/augustl/js-unzip

Answer (score 1):

There are existing libraries, here is one (as an example): http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/

Comment: I dont't see any unzip libs on that site - where exactly is the part that can unzip zip files?

Comment: As far as I can tell the library you linked to links to native libraries to do things like decompressing. That is: it cannot be used from the browser, you need to run a custom interpreter on your local system to make use of it. That is useful, but not for a Firefox 3.6 demo.

Comment: Yes, it is a standalone JS container, which is not quite what you are after. There must be some way to get to Firefox's underlying JS Engine, which unfortunately means you will probably need to write an extension