# I want to unzip a file with javascript from a file or blob object

Tags: javascript, file, zip, blob, local

I would like to read a pptx file in javascript, so I would like to unzip it and read the content in memory. I don't want to store the file first on a server. I want to choose a file with a input type file and just use the file of the input-element and read it binary or something like that.

I found a lot of libraries to unzip zip-files from url, I tried to look at the code but I couldn't figure it out to use it for a blob or byte array.

I can read some stuff like the things described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29#File_headers

But I don't know how deflating works on byte- or bit-level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You've said you want to use an `input` element, so I'm guessing this is browser-based JavaScript.)

Your first step will be to use the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) to read the file as a [binary string](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#binary-string). See [my answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146483/html5-file-api-read-as-text-and-binary/3146509#3146509) for an example of that. Then you'll need to find a library. A quick search discovered [this one](https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate) that implements both inflate and deflate. (I don't have personal experience using it, just found it in an answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233062/javascript-deflate-implementation).)

Naturally this will only work on quite modern browsers that support the File API. Otherwise, you have no option but to push the file to a server and do the work there, since you can't access the content of the file in the browser without the File API.

Comment: But if I read the zip-file as a binary string the file headers will be in that string and those don't need to be deflated.

Comment: @user709455: You'll have to work through the details of the pptx format. There's no shortcut barring your finding a client-side JavaScript library that's already been built that understands pptx files.

Comment: but a pptx file is just a zip file... i only need to extract it and read the file that are inside

Comment: @user709455: Then you need something that understands the zip file format, not just the `deflate` algorithm. [Here's a question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163857/unzipping-zip-archives-with-javascript-in-firefox-3-6) here on SO that talks about doing that.

Comment: well, yes, that's the problem... I only find libraries that use a url to a file on a server... And as explained above I can't work out how they work with the binarystream they get from the XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @user709455: If you look inside the ZipFile.complete.js file in the library I pointed to, you'll see that it's just reading the full text of the response and then wrapping a convenience object it's called a `BinaryUrlStream` around it. In your case, you can read the text directly rather than having to do the ajax request. Shouldn't be that big a deal to do what it does in its `readyState == 4` logic. Barring finding a library that already does what you want, there's nothing for it but to do the coding -- or farm it out, a lot of us here are consultants. ;-)